# Npm won't install quick.db, returns these errors

Tags: npm, quick.db

I am trying to install quick.db for my discord.js bot, and when I attempted installing by running these two commands:

```
npm -g --add-python-to-path install windows-build-tools node-gyp
```

and

```
npm i quick.db
```

It returns me [this error](https://pastebin.com/sHWhtEMu)

Here is the [log](https://nofile.io/f/MSeKUAvD2mf/2019-03-13T23_30_45_572Z-debug.log)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you restarted your console?

Comment: If you mean CMD, then yes. Otherwise I am not sure what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix it! All you have to do is click modify under Visual Studio Community in the installer, go to the dropdown list in "Desktop Development with C++" and check the box marked "VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset for desktop" and install it!

I found this solution [here!](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/48806/cant-find-v140-in-visual-studio-2017.html)

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.
It is easy. Follow these steps:

1- Click on the windows-key of your keyboard to open the windows menu

2- Type cmd/PowerShell (It's totally your choice) and right-click on the first result

3- Click `Run as Administrator`

4- When the terminal is opened type npm install --global windows-build-tools --vs2015 in it and the installation will start. (Sometimes this can take longer)

5- When the installation is finished you can close the terminal.

6- Now you must go to the directory where you want to install Quick.db.

7- Hold Left-Shift and right-click on a blank space of the directory.

8- Click on "Open PowerShell window here".

9- If you see a file named "package.json" in your folder skip to 11

10- Type `npm init -y` in the terminal

11- Type `npm i quick.db`