# NPM throws error while installing quick.db

Tags: database, sqlite, npm, quick.db

I am trying to install quick.db to get started with databases and SQLite3 specifically, but when I try installing it, it always throws an error. The NPM version I have is 6.14.11 and Node version is v14.16.0.

```
> better-sqlite3@7.1.2 install E:\JAVASCRIPT\Tutorials\DATABASES\node_modules\better-sqlite3                                                          
> prebuild-install || npm run build-release                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                      
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=14.16.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)                                  
                                                                                                                                                      
> better-sqlite3@7.1.2 build-release E:\JAVASCRIPT\Tutorials\DATABASES\node_modules\better-sqlite3                                                    
> node-gyp rebuild --release                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                      
E:\JAVASCRIPT\Tutorials\DATABASES\node_modules\better-sqlite3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )                                                                                       
gyp ERR! find VS                                                                                                                                      
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config                                                                                 
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt                                                                               
gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer                                                                         
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015                                                                                                       
gyp ERR! find VS - not found                                                                                                                          
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8                                                                       
gyp ERR! find VS                                                                                                                                      
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************                                                                       
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio                                                                              
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.                                                                               
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:                                                                                   
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows                                                                                        
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************                                                                       
gyp ERR! find VS                                                                                                                                      
gyp ERR! configure error                                                                                                                              
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use                                                                            
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)        
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16                                   
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)                                                                                                                                              
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14                                   
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16                                  
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7                                                 
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16                                                
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)                                                                               
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)                                                                                            
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)                                                                                  
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041                                                                                                                 
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"                                                                                                                                       
gyp ERR! cwd E:\JAVASCRIPT\Tutorials\DATABASES\node_modules\better-sqlite3                                                                            
gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0                                                                                                                             
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0                                                                                                                           
gyp ERR! not ok                                                                                                                                       
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                                                              
npm ERR! errno 1                                                                                                                                      
npm ERR! better-sqlite3@7.1.2 build-release: `node-gyp rebuild --release`                                                                             
npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                                                                                                
npm ERR!                                                                                                                                              
npm ERR! Failed at the better-sqlite3@7.1.2 build-release script.                                                                                     
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.                                                    
                                                                                                                                                      
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                                                                                                  
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gigabyte\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-14T09_23_59_004Z-debug.log                                                     
npm WARN databases@1.0.0 No description                                                                                                               
npm WARN databases@1.0.0 No repository field.                                                                                                         
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):                                                               
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                      
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                                                              
npm ERR! errno 1                                                                                                                                      
npm ERR! better-sqlite3@7.1.2 install: `prebuild-install || npm run build-release`                                                                    
npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                                                                                                
npm ERR!                                                                                                                                              
npm ERR! Failed at the better-sqlite3@7.1.2 install script.                                                                                           
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.                                                    
                                                                                                                                                      
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                                                                                                  
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gigabyte\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-14T09_23_59_397Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you read what the error tells you and try doing what it says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After juggling through the internet, I finally found the correct answer that works.

Here is the link to that:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55152761/npm-wont-install-quick-db-returns-these-errors#:~:text=All%20you%20have%20to%20do,I%20found%20this%20solution%20here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55152761/npm-wont-install-quick-db-returns-these-errors#:%7E:text=All%20you%20have%20to%20do,I%20found%20this%20solution%20here)!

The first answer is perfect!